# C++ arrays and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I was wondering if someone could clear this up for me. It concerns pointers and arrays.

```
double wages[3] = {10000.0, 20000.0, 30000.0};
double * pw = wages;
```

In the above example one can access an element in the array the following two ways:

```
wages[1] or 
*(wages+ 1)
```

Then I stumbled upon another piece of code:

```
void fill(std::array<double, Seasons> * pa)
{   
    using namespace std;
    for (int i = 0; i < Seasons; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter " << Snames[i] << " expenses: ";
        cin >> (*pa)[i];
    }
}
```

Why can't we write `pa[i]` since pa is a pointer. Isn't it the same as the example above?

Comment: Think that if the function declaration would be void fill(std::array<double, Seasons> & pa), the cin line would be cin>>pa[i], because, in your example [] is applied on the std::array, not on the pointer. If you want you can write (pa[0])[i] --> but don't do it, since it's ugly as hell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pa` is a pointer to an object, the type of which is `std::array<double, Seasons>`.

`pa[i]` will not get you the i'th double in the `std::array`, it will attempt to access another `std::array` in memory that wasn't allocated for it, and will result in undefined behavior.

`(*pa)` results in a reference to a `std::array` object, which implements `operator[]`.
`(*pa)[i]` calls `operator[]` of `std::array` on the aforementioned object.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't we write pa[i] since pa is a pointer.

`pa` is pointer to array. So `pa[i]` does not dereference the `i`th element of the current array as you would expect - that syntax works as if `pa` is array of pointers instead.

`(*pa)[i]` dereference the `i`th element of the array pointed by `pa`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also access that element using pa->at(i) instead of pa.at(i) as pa is a pointer.